# Should an API return calculated values that the consumer can calculate themselves?

Tags: api, api-design

Say an API returns the following pieces of data:

- daily_price
- number_of_days
- total_price

Assume that the API will always have the `number_of_days` and *at least* `daily_price` or `total_price`.

In cases when the API only has the `daily_price` or `total_price`, should the API compute the missing value (e.g. `daily_price` * `number_of_days` = `total_price`) - or should it leave it to the consumer to  calculate? And if the API did compute the missing value, should it indicate which of the two values (if any) was computed?

Comment: Try to model the domain (don't just make stuff up as the programmer).  If the domain shows receipts with quantity * price = subtotal, then do that, but consult not other programmers, but the domain experts.  Inspect the positioning of the API to see who the clients are and how this information ought to be communicated between the business roles involved (API consumer(s), API provider(s)), so as to mimic a business/domain interaction.  If the API is internal to the business, then perhaps it doesn't matter, but even internally we can be sharing information between business roles/departments.

Comment: I'd be more interesting in whatever or not there is an appropiate way for the API to express that a value is missing. Consumer code should create an adapter anyway, and there it can deal with the missing value with whatever logic is prefered. Thus, arguebly expressing a missing value, if possible, is more flexible. The flip side is that abstracting this away from consumers could be part of the requirements for the system. Is it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The mistake is mixing them together.

If the api provides totals it shouldn't provide what it used to arrive at that total.

If the api provides the dependencies used to calculate the total it shouldn't also calculate the total.

The reason why is because these are two different levels of abstraction. You can provide both api's but they should be separate beasts. You should be able to use one without getting the other in the bargain.

Look at your using code when making these decisions. Don't just look at the data and try to imagine all of it's uses. Start from the real uses you have now.

Answer (score 5):

> Should an API return calculated values that the consumer can calculate themselves?

**Short answer:**

Yes.

**Long  answer:**

What are the advantages for letting the client compute the missing information? Are you saving bandwidth because there is less bytes transmitted over the network? Do you have a cleaner API by not returning derived data from the core data? What's the reason to not just compute this field?

Even if you have a reason. What you are doing is increase the coupling between your server API and your clients. If, for example, you return `daily_price` and `number_of_days` then the client needs to compute `total_price`. Always.

What if at some point this is no longer a multiplication? But some other other rules start to apply? Maybe new regulations introduced? I'm speculating here but what if taxes apply beyond a certain total amount? What if you want to apply discounts for certain total amounts? And a bunch of any other cases that changes the rules of the game?

If the rules change at some point, are you going to contact all your clients and have them change their code to now handle the new rule? **This is your API, thus your responsibility. Don't put part of the responsibility for your API on your clients.** Just add the derived/redundant data to your responses. You are not gaining anything if you don't.

Comment: One advantage of having client the compute the missing information is reducing the error space. Any redundancy is a possible inconsistency; you may actually make the client's life *harder* by providing additional information which can be logically derived from the basic information, because now in order to validate the API responses, a robust client will have to verify that the computed value is correct *and* will have to decide what to do if the information is inconsistent.

Comment: @ChristianHackl: Getting the computation wrong on the client is just as easy as getting it wrong on the server. Besides, this can easily be cought by the unit tests of the API. Having this field tested by the client might make it robust, as you say, but it also opens up a can of worms. If the client doesn't trust this field in the response, what else doesn't it trust? How far are you willing to go to complicate the client code just to check that the API does what it's supposed to do?

Comment: Whether the client or the API is more likely to get the computation wrong depends on many things. It is also not true in my experience that testing an API means that clients need not perform any error handling, unless you are dealing with an extremely stable and robust API, e.g. something provided by your own operating system. Additionally, you may eventually have no control over how the API is developed and tested, anyway.

Comment: @ChristianHackl: Error handling is one thing, not trusting the API you are calling and deciding to add code to double check for stuff is another.

Comment: Example new rule: Buy 3 weeks and get your 4th week free! Daily price = $10, number of days = 28, total price = $210.

Comment: @Bogdan: Where do you draw the line between error handling and "not trusting" the API? For example, would you verify that the price is positive?

Comment: @ChristianHackl: From what you said in your first comment I gathered that you think the client is somehow obligated to validate the computed field, just because it's a computed field. What I'm saying is, I would not do that unless I have reasons to do so. You ask *would you verify that the price is positive?* It depends if the price has ever been negative. If I have reasons to doubt the API, then I might put some checks in place to avoid displaying something weird to users because someone screwed up on the API. I trust the API unless proven otherwise. I don't eagerly validate the API responses

Comment: @ChristianHackl: Another reason (besides trust) of why I would not validate the computed field in the client is what I mentioned in my answer to this post: if I add some validation on the client to check the field, and then the rules to compute the field change on the server side, the client will now (falsely) identify a perfectly valid rule change as an error in the response. You then have to change the client code to account for the new rule. As a client I shouldn't really care about that.

Comment: @Bogdan: I suppose your trust comes from your personal experience with very well-implemented, robust APIs, and in that context, client-side validation becomes less of a concern. In contrast, the most expensive (in terms of real money spent) project I've ever worked on also had the worst API I've ever worked with as a client developer. It was a largely undocumented JSON REST API with funny stuff like fields whose semantics mysteriously depended on whether the identifier was lowercase or not (I think it was "Id" vs "id"). The client could not have survived without validation.

Comment: @Bogdan: As for your last point, it depends on the original semantics, which must be part of the API documentation. If the rule is fixed in the first place, then the API implementation cannot simply change; it would effectively be a new version of the API. If the rule is documented as implementation-dependent, then the question becomes moot, because in that case client validation is impossible anyway.